# Why "niente di nuovo", not "niente nuovo"?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

I have encountered the following sentence in my Rosetta Stone program:

> Non c'è niente di nuovo in questa camera.

Why does the adjective `nuovo` not directly modify the noun `niente`? In other words, why does the whole sentence not become the following:

> Non c'è niente nuovo in questa camera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained by @Tobia, "niente" is an indefinite pronoun, which in this sentence is synonym to "qualcosa", followed by "di nuovo" which has the function of what is called a "complemento partitivo", as you can see [in this link](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=qualcosa). In can't be "nuovo" without the preposition "di" because such a complement is always introduced with preposition "di", "tra" o "fra" as you can see in these links:

> - [Complemento partitivo](http://www.italiano-online.it/complemento_partitivo.html)
> - [Complemento partitivo nella Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/complemento-partitivo_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/)
> - ["Complemento partitivo" explained in English](http://italian-grammar.italianforyou.com/syntax/sentence/complements/partitive/syntax-sentence-complements-partitive.php)

Comment: I still can't get it. Is it true that whenever you modify an indefinite pronoun, you always modify it using a preposition (or what you call `complemento partitivo`)? Or is `nuovo` the special case here and the rule can be different in other adjectives?

Comment: @Gardecolo: Not always: "niente", as "qualcosa", can also be followed by "altro" ("nient'altro"). But the construction "indefinite pronoun" + "complemento partitivo" is very usual (also with other adjectives).

Comment: @Gardecolo: For instance, "niente di meglio", "niente di simile", "niente di buono", "niente di bello", "niente di personale", ...

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it's not a noun in the context you provided, but a pronoun.

Specifically mentioned in:

http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/niente/

> c. Col sign. del pron. indef. qualcosa, per lo più in proposizione
>   interrogativa: sai n.?, c’è n. di nuovo?, desidera nient’altro? Con
>   uso e valore simile nella locuz. non per n., formula di attenuazione
>   con cui si introduce una domanda o un’affermazione che si presume
>   indiscreta: non per n., ma si potrebbe sapere dove andate?; con altro
>   sign., non per n., non a caso, non senza un motivo: non per n. hanno
>   scelto proprio lui!

Comment: We have the [best practice](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/a/6/8) of answering in English to a question posed in English and in Italian to a question posed in Italian. Please, make an effort to translate the Italian citation into English or, at least, make a short English summary of it, to make sure that the OP would be able to fully understand your answer.